# Use form controls inside table and add merge functionality in angular 9

Tags: angular, forms, merge

Is it possible to add **form controls** inside a **table cells**, and add **merge** funcionality to this table cells. For example, if I merge two cells one of the controls will fill the empty space?
I need to create some kind of simple spreadsheet and need merge cells, but I am not sure if it is possible this way.
I will use this table data to fill mysql database.

Comment: Impossible is nothing :). take a look this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64548588/angular-binding-data-to-table-multi-ngfor/64550328#64550328. the SO is about rowspan, but the idea should be the same for colspan

Comment: Ok, thanks, but what if inside this cells are dynamically inserted form controls wrapped inside div? And user need to click cell or button to change rowspan?

Comment: The question is too broad because you don't indicate how your dbs schema is. I wite a "answer" to indicate how start. I hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

The question is too broad because you don't indicate how your dbs schema is. Futhermore, I don't know if your sheet has fixed columns and rows or not

I can imagine that the elements of your table has only two fields, row and value, so you has a service that ask about your table and gets an array of elements like,e.g.

```
[
{row:0,value:"1|2|@-@|4|5"},
{row:1,value:"6|@-@|@-@|7"}
]
```

the idea is create an array of arrays "grid", each element in the way `{colspan:0,control:new FormControl()}`, colspan becomes 1 if one cell is ocupped, 2 if colspan=2.. and 0 if has no cell.

Some like

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.grid = [];
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe((res: any[]) => {
      let maxCols = 0;
      res.forEach(row => {
        this.grid[row.row] = [];
        const value = row.value.split("|");
        let colpos = 0;
        if (value.length > maxCols) maxCols = value.length;
        value.forEach((col, index) => {
          if (col == "@-@") {
            this.grid[row.row][colpos].colspan++;
            this.grid[row.row][index] = {
              colspan: 0,
              control: new FormControl()
            };
          } else {
            colpos = index;
            this.grid[row.row][index] = {
              colspan: 1,
              control: new FormControl(col)
            };
          }
        });
      });
      //fill the grid with maxCols and MaxRows
      for (let i = 0; i < this.grid.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < maxCols; j++) {
          if (!this.grid[i]) this.grid[i] = [];
          if (!this.grid[i][j])
            this.grid[i][j] = { colspan: 1, control: new FormControl() };
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

And

```
<div class="table">
    <table class="table table-bordered" style="border: 2px">
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let row of grid;let i=index">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let col of row;let j=index;">
                    <td *ngIf="col.colspan>=1" 
            [attr.colspan]="col.colspan>1?col.colspan:null">
                        <input [formControl]="col.control">
                    </td>
                </ng-container>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Now, the hard part: imagine the way to join cells and separate, add columns and rows... happy coding :)

See the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma616776096433166-fgi8gd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: thanks, I will try to work with your example, and also will try to make rowspan. Thanks.