# How can I position an element on n cells of an html table? Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, html-table

How can I position an element correctly on a table? The problem is that the table is dynamic, there can be n columns and n rows, then both width and height can change.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KIkM.png)

My intention here is that according to a start and end time are the height of the element and the place of the column where it is located.

I leave an example of my code and attempts.
[Stackblitz live code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xxwqip?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Typescript.

```
  hours = [
    '8:00 AM',
    '9:00 AM',
    '10:00 AM',
    '11:00 AM',
    '12:00 PM',
    '1:00 PM',
    '2:00 PM',
    '3:00 PM',
    '4:00 PM',
    '5:00 PM',
  ];
  places = ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5'];
  events: any = [];

  cellWidth = 0;
  cellWidthHour = 0;
  cellHeight = 0;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.getCellSize();
    this.createEvent('10:00 AM', '12:00 PM', 'P3');
  }

  getCellSize() {
    const cell = document.getElementsByClassName('cell')[0];
    const cellWidthHour = document.getElementsByClassName('cell-hour')[0];
    const cellRect = cell.getBoundingClientRect();
    const cellRectHour = cellWidthHour.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.cellWidth = cellRect.width;
    this.cellHeight = cellRect.height;
    this.cellWidthHour = cellRectHour.width;
    console.log(this.cellWidth, this.cellHeight);
  }

  createEvent(startTime: string, endTime: string, location: string) {
    const event: any = { startTime, endTime, location };
    event.position = this.calculateEventPosition(startTime, endTime, location);
    this.events.push(event);
  }

  calculateEventPosition(startTime: string, endTime: string, location: string) {
    const start = this.hours.indexOf(startTime) + 1;
    const end = this.hours.indexOf(endTime);

    const place = this.places.indexOf(location);

    const height = (end - start + 1) * this.cellHeight + 3;
    const top = start * this.cellHeight - 6;
    const left = place * this.cellWidth + this.cellWidthHour;

    console.log(start, end, place);
    console.log(height, top, left);

    return {
      height: height + 'px',
      top: top + 'px',
      left: left + 'px',
      width: this.cellWidth + 'px',
    };
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="calendar-container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th *ngFor="let place of places">{{ place }}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let hour of hours">
      <td class="cell-hour">{{ hour }}</td>
      <td class="cell" *ngFor="let place of places"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div *ngFor="let event of events">
    <div class="event" [ngStyle]="event.position">
      <p>{{ event.location }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.calendar-container {
  position: relative;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
}

table td {
  height: 25px;
}

.event {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

I tried to generate these elements that are like cards in a dynamic way but I could not find the correct formula, sometimes it overflows or when I place it well just by readjusting the screen I lose the effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the "padding" in your "event class"

Use `box-sizing: border-box;` or remove the padding, [to know more about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model#what_is_the_css_box_model)

```
.event {
  box-sizing: border-box;    /*Add this*/
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 12px;             /*Or remove this*/
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

BTW if you don't want to drag the "events, only show, I suggest use colspan and rowspan like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64548588/angular-binding-data-to-table-multi-ngfor/64550328#64550328https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64548588/angular-binding-data-to-table-multi-ngfor/64550328#64550328)

NOTE: I like more get the cells directly and not based the calculus in your `getCellSize`:

```
calculateEventPosition(startTime: string, endTime: string, location: string) {
    const rect=document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    const columns=document.getElementsByClassName('cell-place');
    const rows=document.getElementsByClassName('cell-hour');
    const column=Array.from(columns).find(x=>x.innerHTML==location);
    const start=rows.item(this.hours.indexOf(startTime))
    const end=rows.item(this.hours.indexOf(endTime))

    const left=column.getBoundingClientRect().left-rect.left+1;
    const top = start.getBoundingClientRect().top-rect.top+1;
    const width=column.getBoundingClientRect().width-2;
    const height=end.getBoundingClientRect().top-start.getBoundingClientRect().top-2;

    return {
      height: height + 'px',
      top: top + 'px',
      left: left + 'px',
      width: width + 'px',
    };
  }
```